# Forward slash on URLs in the Sitemap file?

Tags: url, sitemap

At the following page:

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668#2

the URLs given in the Sitemap example don't have a forward slash at the end.

But I think I heard somewhere that they should.

In my Sitemap file, should I include a forward slash `/` on the end of each URL?

Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URLs you use in your Sitemap should be the same canonical URLs you use on your site. If you include a trailing slash when linking between your pages then include a trailing slash in your site. Whether URLs end with a trailing slash is generally up to you - there isn't necessarily any right or wrong way of doing it.

If your URLs map directly to files on the filesystem then arguably they should only have a forward slash at the end if you are linking to a "directory" and your page is the default document within that directory eg. `index.html`, `index.php`, etc. But this should also be how you link to the page within your site. The forward slash is simply to avoid any ambiguity, to indicate it is a directory and not a file. (By default on Apache, if you link to a file system directory and omit the trailing slash then mod_dir triggers a 301 external redirect to append a trailing slash - to "fix" the URL.)

For example, it is generally preferred to not link to the default document in the directory:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/index.html
```

You should simply show the URL as the following (with a trailing slash):

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/
```

As mentioned, the trailing slash removes any ambiguity. If you omit the trailing slash, it will *probably* still work, but it first looks for a file called `to` before realising it's a directory.

The URLs in the sitemap example at the address given do not have a forward slash at the end because they are linking to specific HTML files on the filesystem, eg. `http://example.com/foo.html`. In this case, if you simply append a trailing slash it will likely generate a 404 Not Found response on Apache. (Because the `text/html` handler does not accept path_info by default.)

Incidentally, this relates more to how you link to files within your site - not just the Sitemap.

Comment: thanks w3d -- so on my site, if I don't add a slash or index.php, it goes to my homepage -- does this mean i dont add the slash? the site is http://wordfruit.com

Comment: I think you should include the trailing slash in the sitemap URL. You do seem to be linking to "/" in your home links, so you are actually linking to `http://wordfruit.com/`. The browser seems to treat site-root links a bit different anyway, in that it appears to automatically append the trailing slash when a user types `somedomain.com` in their browser. However, sub pages do seem to be different.

Comment: ...Sub pages cont... for example, you link to `http://wordfruit.com/copywriters`, which implies a file called 'copywriters', but the actual page returned by the server is `http://wordfruit.com/copywriters/index.php`. The server has had to do some extra processing in order to work this out since there is no file called 'copywriters'. Ideally you should include `http://wordfruit.com/copywriters/` in your sitemap (and in your site link).